# Preventing index.php?category_name=something from redirecting

Tags: categories, url-rewriting, templates, redirect, rewrite-rules

I'm trying to filter posts in a category by the year of the post's date. I also want to do this without being redirected to the year template so my ideal URL would be http://example.com/category/reports/2011/ which would load the template file category.php where I could then use query_posts to include only the posts that were published in 2011 and are in the reports category.

Here is my rewrite rule code...

```
function filter_category_by_year_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) {
    /* Creates rewrite rules for filtering category archives by year (/category/reports/2011/)*/
    $new_rules = array(
        "category/(.+?)/(\d\d\d\d)/?$" => "index.php?category_name=" . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . "&year=" . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2)
    );
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
    var_dump($wp_rewrite);
}
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'filter_category_by_year_rewrite_rules');
```

My problem is WordPress automatically redirects `index.php?category_name=reports&year=2011` to `/category/reports/` with no trace of the year parameter. How can I intercept this redirect?

I tried hooking in to the `template_redirect` action to no avail :(

```
function testing_redirect() {
    global $wp;
    if($wp->request['matched_rule'] == 'category/(.+?)/(\d\d\d\d)/?$') {
        load_template( 'category.php' ); //TEMPLATEPATH .'/category.php';
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'testing_redirect', 1);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpa12742_init' );

function wpa12742_init(){
  add_rewrite_rule( 'category/(.+?)/(\d{4})/?$', 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&year=$matches[2]', 'top' );
  add_rewrite_rule( 'category/(.+?)/(\d{4})/page/(\d+)/?$', 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&year=$matches[2]&paged=$matches[3]', 'top' );
}
```

### EDIT

On second thought, that's not enough, since you'll get caught by `redirect_canonical()`.

Add this too:

```
add_filter( 'term_link', 'wpa12743_term_link', 10, 3 );

function wpa12743_term_link( $link, $term, $taxonomy ){
  if('category' != $taxonomy && !preg_match( '@^\d{4}$@', get_query_var('year') ) )
    return $link;
  return trailingslashit( $link ) . get_query_var( 'year' );
}
```

Comment: You're right, canonical_redirect was the problem. See my answer below this one for how I solved it. Did you mean to filter `term_link` and not `redirect_canonical`?  I kind of like you're way better for the trailing slash.

Comment: Cool! I did mean to filter term link, but your method works just fine. :)

Answer (score 4):

Ahhh `redirect_canonical` was the culprit. Here's how I weeded this bugger out...

```
function kill_canonical_redirect($redirect_url, $requested_url) {
    global $wp;
    if($wp->matched_rule == 'category/(.+?)/(\d\d\d\d)/?$') { 
        return false;
    } else {
        return $redirect_url;
    }
}
add_filter('redirect_canonical', 'kill_canonical_redirect', 10, 2);
```

Basically I look at the rewrite rule that matched the page request and if it is the one I wrote then I know I can kill the canonical redirect by simply returning false.

Perhaps the more helpful info for anyone reading over this is how I figured this out. I installed the Better HTTP Redirects plugin ( http://hakre.wordpress.com/2011/03/20/how-to-debug-redirect-problems-in-wordpress/ ) which has a really handy redirect debugging tool when `WP_DEBUG` is set to true in `wp-config.php`.

From there I realized the redirect was being triggered from Line 367 of `/wp-includes/canonical.php` so after looking at the source code on Trac ( http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/canonical.php#L367 ), I figured out how to kill the canonical redirect.

Comment: A really really crazy good tool for looking through core is PHPXref: http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/wordpress/nav.html

Comment: +1 The canonical redirects were really annoying me until I found this. Thanks!